# How can some code be executed if "HTTP response" was not successfully sent on a JAX-WS web service method

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-ee-7

I have the following service:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "ServiceXPTO")
public class ServiceXPTO {
    @EJB
    private XPTO ejbRef;
    @WebMethod(operationName = "webmethod1")
    public Method1Result webmethod1(
            Method1Request request) {
        return ejbRef.ejbmethod1(request);
    }
}
```

How can I make some code run if after returning from the **webmethod1** there is  some Socket error due cliente disconnects , etc ?

For exemple: if **java.io.IOException** occurs I would like to **ejbRef.*method1Error***(...) be called...

The real Exception:

```
    Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[ServiceXPTO]: Servlet.service() for servlet ServiceXPTO threw exception
    java.io.IOException: Uma ligação estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador anfitrião 
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.flushByteBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:149)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOUtils.writeCompositeBuffer(TCPNIOUtils.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write0(TCPNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:70)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleWrite(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleWrite(TransportFilter.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:848)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.write(FilterChainContext.java:817)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:1024)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushBinaryBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:1011)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flushAllBuffers(OutputBuffer.java:982)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:737)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:175)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:103)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:225)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:259)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.flush(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:71)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:103)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:192)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.writeTo(MessageWrapper.java:226)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:144)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:636)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:878)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:422)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:169)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can get something like that in the form of a CDI interceptor. The only caveat here is that CDI and the [`sun-jaxws.xml` web service config file don't play well together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522999/cdi-injection-in-jax-ws-endpoint-does-not-work-results-in-npe). If you're not bothered by that, I could give you a working sample

Comment: @kolossus I would like to explore that. I will apreciate if you could give me a working sample. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [try/catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html)

```
public Method1Result method1(
        Method1Request request) {
     try{
       return ejbRef.method1(request);
     } catch(IOException e){
        //catch IO exceptions
        return ejbRef.method1Error(request);
     } catch(Exception e){
        //other exceptions
        return ejbRef.method2Error(request);
     } finally{
       //this will always be executed after the try block
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was referring to the web method return... when the framework will serialize the response and send the response to the web client. (I edited my question to try to be clearer)

Comment: You should be able to use the same thing, you don't need to return anything from your catch block. You can invoke any method you like and bubble up the error response to the user.

Comment: The case I'm testing and trying to control is when the client drops! 
If the client drops and I can not deliver the response I need to cancel what I previous done in ejbRef.ejbmethod1, a sort of db roll back(but not quite the same because i need to update a record with this error and consume a external web servisse, because of that I need to call another method to do the "cancelation", JPA/JTA will not do )